# Get height of element inside iframe with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, height

I have a file containing an "iframe" element

```
<iframe src="test.php" width="100%" id="frameDemo"></iframe>
```

and a file test.php containing a div of unknown height.

```
<div>some content...</div>
```

I would like to create a Jquery script to get the height of the div inside the iframe.
 
I've tried the following but I receive a null response.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var mydiv = $( "#frameDemo" ).contents().find("div");
    var h = mydiv.height();
    alert(h);
});
```

Can anybody please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming the iframe is on the same domain (otherwise it's not possible), you should wait for the iframe to load first :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#frameDemo" ).on('load', function() { 
        var mydiv = $(this).contents().find("div");
        var h     = mydiv.height();
        alert(h);
    });
});
```

Comment: Does not work in my case, the file is on the same domain, but i does not see the elements inside the iframe :(