# HTML <object> fit height of its content

Tags: html, css, object, height

I'm trying to use a `<object type='text/html' data='/forum'></object>` to show a phpbb forum inside a content div with `width:800px; min-height:525px;`.

The div with normal content is resizing so it is getting longer as the content grows. But the `object` type only holds the height value and makes a scrollbar. If I set no height or `height:auto` on the object it does not fully expand to the `divContent` size. If I set the height or min-height fits, but always makes scrollbars.

How can I make the `<object>` container auto size as the content is getting longer?

Comment: Why are you using `<object>` instead of `<iframe>` in the first place?

Comment: No reason, other than i was in that beleave that the iframe was absolute. But if iframe is a better choise then no problem for me.

Comment: Then please do some research on how to do this with an iframe – that has been discussed before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As correctly pointed out in comments, you can include your forum inside an `iframe`.

```
<iframe src="forum.html" width="100%" id="yourframe"></iframe>
```

Then you can get `div` height inside iframe, as shown in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504086/get-height-of-element-inside-iframe-with-jquery). And finally, you can use this height to resize iframe, according to its content.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#yourframe" ).on('load', function() { 
        var mydiv = $(this).contents().find("div");
        var h = mydiv.height();
        $(this).height(h);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks both, for pointing in the rigth direction :)

i ended up ofcouse using iframe, thanks Quentin.
using the following JavaScript:

```
function ResizeIframe(id){
  var frame = window.parent.document.getElementById('iframe');
  frame.style.height = frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
 }
```

and html:

```
echo "<iframe id='iframe' onload='ResizeIframe(\"iframe\")' src='/forum' style='width:100%; min-height:525px; border:0px; overflow-y:hidden;'></iframe>";
```

Giorgio > i will look futher into your method. Thanks.