# How to resize appened iframe to its content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, height

As the title, how to resize appened iframe to content?
I have already referred other questions:

- [jquery get height of iframe content when loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846132/jquery-get-height-of-iframe-content-when-loaded)
- [Resize iframe to content with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872394/resize-iframe-to-content-with-jquery)
- [Get height of element inside iframe with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504086/get-height-of-element-inside-iframe-with-jquery)

, but it is still not working. The following are my codes:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#appendIframeHere').append("<iframe src=\"http://www.w3schools.com/\"></iframe>");
  var iframe = $('#appendIframeHere').find('iframe');
  iframe.css("width", "100%");
  iframe.css("height", iframe.contents().find('body').height() );
  $('#appendIframeHere').text(iframe.contents().find('body').height());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="appendIframeHere"></div>
```

------------------------------------------------------------update------------------------------------------------------------

[image]
I use the same way to get `height()` but it has different value, 0 and 2786. I tried to add a callback function to `append()` but I have seen some reference said that `append()` complete immediately so  I don't have to use callback. After that I also tried `promise().done(function(){...})` to `append()` but it still get different value from js file and console.

Comment: Check the console: `Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame`. This is because the Same Origin Policy is stopping you from accessing the content of a third-party domain through an iframe. There is nothing you can do to stop this as it's a security feature. Also note that jQuery 1.2.3 is *incredibly* outdated. I would strongly suggest you upgrade. I'd also suggest you stop using W3Schools as a guide as their information is usually incorrect and often outdated - as in this example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Um...okay, my bad! This is not a good example. My real problem is to link other `html` in the same folder.

Comment: Perhaps you can also try: `$('#appendIframeHere iframe').style.height = $('#appendIframeHere iframe').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';`

Comment: @Ren I tried your way but there was an error message saying cannot read property `document` of undefined.

Comment: Oh, looks like problem is due to cross-domain iframes, so we don't have access to the child DOM. Maybe you can make use of pluggins like: http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/ made for such purposes.